# JavaScript nested inner for loop not working

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to store the common strings from `bobsFollower` array and `tinasFollower` array in `mutualFollowers` array.

```js
const bobsFollowers = ['vinit','vidyesh','bipin','shobhana'];
const tinasFollowers = ['vinit','vidyesh','manish'];
const mutualFollowers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < bobsFollowers.length; i++){
  for (let j = 0; j < tinasFollowers.lenght; j++){
    if (bobsFollowers[i] === tinasFollowers[j]){
      mutualFollowers.push(tinasFollowers[j]);
    }     
  }
};
console.log(mutualFollowers);
```

**inner for loop in not getting executed**

Comment: Is `tinasFollowers.lenght` supposed to be `.length`?

Answer (score 1):

You had a typo in the inner loop: you mistyped `length` as `lenght`!

```js
const bobsFollowers = ['vinit','vidyesh','bipin','shobhana'];
const tinasFollowers = ['vinit','vidyesh','manish'];
const mutualFollowers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < bobsFollowers.length; i++){
  for (let j = 0; j < tinasFollowers.length; j++){
    if (bobsFollowers[i] === tinasFollowers[j]){
      mutualFollowers.push(tinasFollowers[j]);
    }     
  }
};
console.log(mutualFollowers);
```

Answer (score 0):

you made a mistake in your code : in the second "for" you wrote "tinasFollowers.lenght" instead of "tinasFollowers.length" ;) 
Here is the correct code :

```
const bobsFollowers = ['vinit','vidyesh','bipin','shobhana'];
const tinasFollowers = ['vinit','vidyesh','manish'];
const mutualFollowers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < bobsFollowers.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < tinasFollowers.length; j++){
        if (bobsFollowers[i] === tinasFollowers[j]){
            mutualFollowers.push(tinasFollowers[j]);
        }
    }
};
console.log(mutualFollowers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Much easier with filter

```js
const bobsFollowers = ['vinit','vidyesh','bipin','shobhana'];

const tinasFollowers = ['vinit','vidyesh','manish'];


const mutualFollowers  = bobsFollowers.filter(element => tinasFollowers.includes(element));

console.log(mutualFollowers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are misspelling length as lenght on the 5th line. and also there is an extra semicolon on the 10th line, which is not causing the error.
Here is the solution.

```
const bobsFollowers = ['vinit','vidyesh','bipin','shobhana'];
const tinasFollowers = ['vinit','vidyesh','manish'];
const mutualFollowers  = [];
for(let i = 0; i < bobsFollowers.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < tinasFollowers.length; j++){
        if(bobsFollowers[i] === tinasFollowers[j]){
            mutualFollowers.push(bobsFollowers[i]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(mutualFollowers );
```